# Fetch data in database into jradiobutton java

Tags: java, mysql, database, jradiobutton

So far i can only get the question in my database table.It looks like this
question in `jtextfield`.
Example:

> - Johnny's mother had three children.The first child was called April,the second child was called May.What was the third child's name?

```
- radiobutton June   
- radiobutton Johny
- radiobutton John   
- radiobutton Johnny
```

How can i put the values in my database table to `jradiobutton`. 
and compare them to the value the user selected.

Answer (score 0):

I am not giving you away the whole thing just a hint: try to understand

- try to understand button group in java. They are just buttons that are clubbed together
- try to populate button group from results of sql query

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: This all i could do right now. It won't display the radio button. This is the code                                                     public void Rbtn(JRadioButton a) throws SQLException{
  
        JRadioButton get = getRadioButton(a);      
    }  
public JRadioButton getRadioButton(JRadioButton a) throws SQLException)
    {
      if(a.isSelected()){    
                 
            String cha="Select *from k_question";
            rs = st.executeQuery(cha);

    } return a ;
    }

Comment: iam having problems on how to get the values from database to jradiobutton

Comment: Cloe you don't have to get values from database into radiobuttons , what you have to do is perhaps get the values from DB and then create jradiobutton in the button group. It can be done in simple for loop over each element in results of sql query.